# Checking when a MySQL server is ready to run queries without interrupting them

Tags: mysql, percona, mysqladmin

I'm using the Percona Docker image, purely for local testing purposes (5.6 because that's what I need to test against).

I want to run an initialization script when the server is ready. I've tried two things so far that have been mentioned in other similar questions: `mysqladmin ping --silent`, and `mysqladmin -uroot status`.

However, in both these cases, when I run the initialization script once they return `0`, the script gets interrupted within a second or two (`ERROR 1317 (70100) at line ___: Query execution was interrupted`). Most of the script runs, but the last few queries don't make it.

If I wait for these commands to return `0`, and *then* sleep for another 5 seconds or so, I don't get interrupted. Why is there this difference in behavior? And how can I test for it before I run the init script so that I don't have to keep an ugly `sleep 5` in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the official Percona docker image starts and shuts MySQL down a couple times before it's fully up, causing the interruptions.

This can be verified with a `docker run percona:5.6`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211256/why-does-mysqld-shutdown-before-starting-in-the-official-percona-docker-image-fo/63211559?noredirect=1#comment111779341_63211559) for more details.